# Facebook approved user_location permission but when I login I didn't get any location

Tags: ios, facebook

FB approved user_location permission but when I login I didn't get any location.

```
- (void)loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(FBLoginView *)loginView
                            user:(id<FBGraphUser>)user {
      NSLog(@"%@",user);
}
```

I am getting below values but not user_location.

Note: Actual values not showing for below keys.

```
{
    email = "---";
    "first_name" = --;
    gender = ---;
    id = --;
    "last_name" = --;
    link = "---";
    locale = "---";
    name = "---";
    timezone = ---;
    "updated_time" = "---";
    verified = ---;
}
```

Please help. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

To turn on Location Services for Facebook on an iPhone/iPad:

```
1.Go to your device's desktop.
2.Tap Settings.
3.Tap Privacy.
4.Select Location Services.
5.Tap near Location Services to turn it on. ...
6.Scroll through the list of apps at the bottom, tap Facebook and select While Using the App or Always.
```

Comment: it is already set to "While Using the App". I've found another solution for my problem. Updating the Fb SDK after getting new permissions solved issue. Thanks for the reply. Could you please undo -1 for my question please.